# Sort by sum of multiple fields

Tags: sorting, lucene.net

I'm using Lucene.Net to index and search. My data contains some numeric fields.
How can I sort search result by sum/multiplying of mulitple numeric fields?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to index an extra field with the calculated value then sort by that.

This is a very common technique in "no-sql" stores. ie denormalise and store whatever extra values are needed to optimise query time performance/capabilities.